How to open `.desktop` files containing a URL link in browser by default (instead of in gedit)?
Consider the following SomeLink.desktop file, which contains a link to some URL:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=SomeLink
Type=Link
URL=https://example.com
Icon=text-html

I've made the file executable via chmod +x SomeLink.desktop and even tried to register it as trusted via gio set SomeLink.desktop metadata::trusted true.
However, when I double click the file in nautilus or use xdg-open SomeLink.desktop it opens in gedit for editing.
I would like to use these "link" files for their primary roles being links, i.e., the double click should in nautilus or xdg-open should open them in the default browser.
How can I achieve this?
Bonus: Any insights into why this is not the default behavior? It feels like a UX flaw to not handle them as one might expect (and I'm pretty sure that was possible for a long time in older Ubuntu versions, no?).
Ubuntu version is 22.04.
